# Access SharePoint Online SQL Server Database with SQL Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using `SharePoint Online` with `Office 365`.

I would like to create a `Table` (I found on google that SharePoint Online uses SQL Server as backend) on the SQL database that SharePoint online connects to.

I did check each setting and links (screenshot below), I cannot find out where `SQL Servers Host, Username, and Password` is hidden.

So I am confused about:

1. How SharePoint online connects to SQL SERVER.
2. Where is the ASP.Net Code behind all dynamic SharePoint pages created, can we access and modify it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online is a Office 365 service. You don't have opportunity to write any custom Server side coding (ASP.NET, C# etc.). And also the backend is managed by SharePoint Online services team (Microsoft), you don't have option to connect to Sql Server.

Workarounds:
Create a SharePoint list, create columns, indexes, views etc. (more like a table in sql) and then query the list either using the REST API(Search services or list services) or the CSOM (client side object model) to query the list to pull data accordingly.

Please let me know if you need any help in understanding.

Comment: is it possible to connect SharePoint Online with SQL Server with purchasing Premium License ? like is there any third Party or some trick to able to connect it ? 
@rare Solution